# Cut out, and replace a part of a string

Tags: javascript

There is a part in my string `from, to` which I would like to replace to an another string `replace_string`. My code should work, but what if there is an another part like the returned substring?

```
var from=10, to=17;
//...

str = str.replace(str.substring(from, to), replace_string);
```

---

For example:

```
from=4,to=6
str = "abceabxy"
replace_string = "zz"
```

the str should be "abcezzxy"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is simple! Cut out and replace the string. Here is the basic tool, you need `scissor` and `glue`! Oops I mean `string.Split()` and `string.Replace()`.

**How to use?**

Well I am not sure if you want to use `string.Split()` but you have used `string.Replace()` so here goes.

String.Replace uses two parameters, like this `("one", "two")` what you need to make sure is that you are not replacing a `char` with a `string` or a `string` with a `char`. They are used as:

```
var str="Visit Microsoft!";
var n=str.replace("Microsoft","W3Schools");
```

**Your code:**

```
var from=10, to=17;
//...
var stringGot = str.replace(str.substring(from, to), replace_string);
```

What you should do will be to split the code first, and then replace the second `a` letter! As you want one in your example. Thats one way!

First, split the string! And then replaced the second `a` letter with `z`.

For String.Replace refer this: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

For String.SubString: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp

For String.Split: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

Comment: You are referring to .NET, while the question is about JavaScript.

Comment: Sorry, I have just editted the question from asp.net to javascript!

Answer (score 1):

Strings are immutable. This means they do not change after they are first instantiated. Every method to manipulate a string actually returns a new instance of a string. So you have to assign your result back to the variable like this:

```
str = str.replace(str.substring(from, to), replace_string);
```

**Update:** However, the more efficient way of doing this in the first place would be the following. it is also less prone to errors:

```
str = str.substring(0, from) + replace_string + str.substring(to);
```

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cFtKL/

It runs both of the commands through a loop 100,000 times. The first takes about 75ms whereas the latter takes 20ms.